# Taylor expansion of $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

How do I compute the Taylor expansion of
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$
around $0$?

Answer (score 4):

First consider the geometric series formula

$$\frac{1}{1 - x} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty x^n, \quad |x| < 1.$$

Differentiating with respect to $x$, we obtain

$$\frac{1}{(1 - x)^2} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty nx^{n-1} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (n + 1)x^n.$$